# Sender becomes Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters]

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I can't figure out why do I have the error "`deadLetters`"

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  private def getIdList = Future { blocking(getIdListSync) }

  private def getIdListSync = {
    val inputStreamRaw = new URL(url).openConnection.getInputStream
    val inputStream = scala.io.Source fromInputStream inputStreamRaw
    val json = parse(inputStream getLines() mkString "\n")
    val jsonIds = json \ "ids" \\ classOf[JInt]
    jsonIds take idLimit map (_.toInt)
  }

  def receive = {
    case Get =>

        //doesn't work, the error is "sender" becomes "Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters]"

//      getIdList onComplete {
//        case Success(idList) =>
//          sender ! Result(idList)
//
//        case Failure(e) => // todo
//      }

      //works well
      val idList = getInternalIdListSync
      sender ! Result(idList)

  }
}
```

As you can see, `sender` becomes `Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters]` in case of using `Future` and `blocking` in the method titled `getIdList`. Why is that? Shouldn't I use that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you call `sender` in an async function block. There is a simple rule for that:

**never close over the sender method in a code block that may get executed asynchronously**

`sender` is a **function** that returns the sender of the currently processed message. The problem is that, if you call `sender` in a callback like `onComplete` this callback gets executed asynchronously. That means that in the meantime the actor may process other messages and therefore the `sender` function may not report the sender of the original message.

One way to avoid that is to store the sender in a local variable before execution asynchronous code:

```scala
def receive = {
  case Get =>
    val s = sender

    // call an asynchronous function
    myAsyncFunction onComplete{ result =>
      s ! result
    }
}
```

Another way is to use the akka `pipeTo` function as @Vadzim pointed out:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

def receive = {
  case Get =>
    // call an asynchronous function
    val result = myAsyncFunction

    result pipeTo sender
}
```

More information about that can be find in the akka documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors

Comment: is it sensible to use async method with Future (getIdList) or should I just use sync method (getIdListSync)?

Comment: That depends on what the task of the actor is. If this is the only task the actor should execute, using the synchronous variant is fine. In this case scaling should happen using multiple actors of the same kind and a dispatcher. On the other side you should consider using the asynchronous variant if the actor should do something else while the list is created.

Comment: Aaaa, so using multithreading (and Futures) is seasonable only if there is another task (or, more than one task overall) to work on while the first one is being executing, correct?

Comment: Right. It doesn't make to much sense to receive messages in an actor and execute all the work asynchronously to immediately receive the next message (dough, there are use cases for that, e.g. to execute tasks on a remote machine). Spawning multiple actors for the same tasks gives you more control (e.g. you can define how much actors should work in parallel)

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
getIdList pipeTo sender
```

See for explanation:
[Akka: Send a future message to an Actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401376/akka-send-a-future-message-to-an-actor)