# Akka/Scala: mapping Future vs pipeTo

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In `Akka` actors, are there any differences - in terms of number of threads being used, or thread locking - between sending a `Future` result to another actor by:

A. mapping the `Future` to function that `tell` the result to the actor.

B. defining an `onSuccess` callback on the future, which `tell` the result to the actor.

C. piping the `Future` result to the actor with `pipeTo`.

Some of these options are discussed in a previous question:

[Akka: Send a future message to an Actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401376/akka-send-a-future-message-to-an-actor)

**Which one of the three is the preferred way to do it, and why?**

**Also,** I would like to know, if `receive` should be of type `Any => Unit`, then **why does the code compile** when in some cases the partial function of `receive` returns a `Future`, not `Unit`?

Here is a code example of the three options that I mentioned above:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.pipe

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.util.Success

class ActorIncrement extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int =>
      println(s"increment $i")
      sender ! i + 1
  }
}

class ActorEven extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int =>
      println(s"$i is even")
  }
}


class ActorOdd extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int =>
      println(s"$i is odd")
  }
}

class MyActor(actorIncrement: ActorRef, actorEven: ActorRef, actorOdd: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

  def receive = {
    case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 =>
      println(s"receive a: $i")
      actorIncrement ? i map {
        case j: Int =>
          println(s"$j from increment a")
          actorOdd ! j
      }
    case i: Int =>
      println(s"receive b: $i")
      val future: Future[Any] = actorIncrement ? i
      future onSuccess {
        case i: Int =>
          println(s"$i from increment b")
          actorEven ! i
      }

    case s: String =>
      println(s"receive c: $s")
      (actorIncrement ? s.toInt).mapTo[Int] filter(_ % 2 == 0) andThen { case Success(i: Int) => println(s"$i from increment c") } pipeTo actorEven
  }
}

object TalkToActor extends App {

  // Create the 'talk-to-actor' actor system
  val system = ActorSystem("talk-to-actor")

  val actorIncrement = system.actorOf(Props[ActorIncrement], "actorIncrement")
  val actorEven = system.actorOf(Props[ActorEven], "actorEven")
  val actorOdd = system.actorOf(Props[ActorOdd], "actorOdd")

  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor(actorIncrement, actorEven, actorOdd)), "myActor")

  myActor ! 2
  myActor ! 7
  myActor ! "11"

  Thread.sleep(1000)

  //shutdown system
  system.terminate()
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at how `pipeTo` is defined in `akka.pattern.PipeToSupport`,

```
def pipeTo(recipient: ActorRef)(implicit sender: ActorRef = 
  Actor.noSender): Future[T] = {
    future andThen {
      case Success(r) ⇒ recipient ! r
      case Failure(f) ⇒ recipient ! Status.Failure(f)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see... `pipeTo` is nothing different than just adding `andThen` call to your `Future` which either sends the future-result or a `Status.Failure` message to the piped actor in case your `Future` fails.

Now the main difference lies in this `Status.Failure` failure-handling. If you are not using `pipeTo`, you can handle your failure in whatever way you want to.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why `Any => Future` is accepted where `Any => Unit` is expected?

Comment: It's called value discarding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238402/what-special-rules-does-the-scala-compiler-have-for-the-unit-type-within-the-typ/41239759#41239759

Comment: @rethab Great. Thanks!