# Identify Akka HttpRequest and HttpResponse?

Tags: scala, http, akka, akka-http

While using **Akka** HttpRequest and pipe the request to an actor, i couldn't identify the response.
The actor will handle each message that will receive but it doesn't know which request used to get this response. Is there any way to identify each request to match the response with ?

Note: i don't have the server to resend any part of request body again.

Thanks in advance

## MySelf.scala

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorLogging }
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.{ ActorMaterializer, ActorMaterializerSettings }
import akka.util.ByteString

class Myself extends Actor with ActorLogging {

import akka.pattern.pipe
import context.dispatcher

final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = 
       ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))

def receive = {
  case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
      log.info("Got response, body: " + body.utf8String)
  }
  case resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _) =>
    log.info("Request failed, response code: " + code)
    resp.discardEntityBytes()
  }

}
```

## Main.scala

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object HttpServerMain extends App {

import akka.pattern.pipe

//  import system.dispatcher
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
// needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

val http = Http(system)

val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MySelf])

http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
    .pipeTo(myActor)

http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io/another-request"))
    .pipeTo(myActor)
Thread.sleep(2000)
system.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `map` to transform the `Future` and add some kind of ID (usually called correlation ID for such purposes) to it before you pipe it to `myActor`:

```
http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
    .map(x => (1, x)).pipeTo(myActor)
```

You'll need to change you pattern match blocks to take a tupple:

```
case (id, HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _)) =>
```

If you can't/don't want to change your pattern match block for some reason you can use same approach, but instead add a unique HTTP header into your completed request (using `copy`) with something like this (not checked if compiles):

```
// make a unique header name that you are sure will not be
// received from http response:
val correlationHeader: HttpHeader = ... // mycustomheader

// Basically hack the response to add your header:
http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
    .map(x => x.copy(headers = correlationHeader +: headers)).pipeTo(myActor)

// Now you can check your header to see which response that was:
case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _) =>
  headers.find(_.is("mycustomheader")).map(_.value).getOrElse("NA")
```

This is more of a hack though compared to previous option because you are modifying a response.

Comment: thanks @yǝsʞǝlA for you answer but for the second choice of using copy can you explain it more

Comment: @MohamedElkady I updated my answer to clarify second option. Not sure if it compiles - I don't have a project at hand to test.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot do that directly using `pipeTo` because it essentially just [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747026/akka-scala-mapping-future-vs-pipeto#answer-47747340) `andThen` call to your `Future`. One option is to`map` and then send a `(request, response)` tuple to actor:

```
val request = HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io")
http.singleRequest(request).map {
  response => myActor ! (request, response)
}

class Myself extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  ...
  def receive = {
    case (request, HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, headers, entity, _)) =>
      ...

    case (request, resp @ HttpResponse(code, _, _, _)) =>
      log.info(request.toString)
      ...
  }
}
```